# Node.JS oauth2 module for paypal authentication

Tags: node.js, oauth, express, oauth-2.0

Is there any node.js module that I can use for paypal oauth authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the Node.js auth solutions support PayPal currently, as far as I'm aware of.  I'm the author of [Passport](http://passportjs.org), and implementing a PayPal auth strategy is on my to-do list.  If you want to get started before I get around to it, let me know and I'll help out.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I used your Passport module it works great. So I prefer to go with Passport. Can you help me how to get started with implementing it with Passport?

Comment: I went ahead and implemented PayPal support, both OpenID and OAuth.  I recommend the OAuth route, but take your pick:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-paypal
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-paypal-oauth

Comment: Thanks Jared. That's really fantastic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any modules specific to PayPal, but if you end up deciding to roll your own, since you're using Express/Connect I would recommend looking into using EveryAuth and just adding a PayPal module to it: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth -- that'll make integrating with any additional authentication APIs much easier in your app's future.